# Saving HTML5 media (audio or video) which is protected

Tags: firefox, video, html5

There are certain cases when HTML5 media embedded with `audio` and `video` tags is not saveable with context menu of built in Firefox player (item "Save as").

For example, embedded Vine video cannot be saved from this page in Firefox 45: https://theconservativetreehouse.com/2016/09/26/polls-polls-polls-ok-who-won-the-debate/

I have checked out the [reference](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/video) ([HTML 5.1 docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/PR-html51-20160915/semantics-embedded-content.html#elementdef-video)) to see whether there are attributes which control this and found none which could relate.

What prevents the browser from showing the "Save as" item? Yes there are extensions like Video Download Helper but what is the native way of doing that?

Comment: What do you mean by "protected"? If there's no DRM I don't consider HTML5 data as "protected".

Comment: Unfortunately I am not competent enough to say that something is protected or not, I caon only say that browser prohibits me to do it. Interestingly, I just tried Chrome which allowed me to save the exemplary video.

Comment: youtube-dl ([homepage](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/)) [supports Vine](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/supportedsites.html), if you haven't been able to download Vine videos yet.

Comment: @user598527 thanks, that's helpful, but the question was primarily about the behaviour itself. One can also download files using F12 console.